# Play sound when microphone is turned on

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there any way to configure Dragon NaturallySpeaking so that whenever the microphone is turned on some sound is played?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: This isn't a feature of Dragon Naturally Speaking

Comment: How about a way that involves something else? Not using Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Comment: @ṧнʊß Good too!